# Event for "onAdLeftApplicationDone"?

Tags: android, admob

New to AdMob, just implemented my first InterstitialAd and it's working fine.

So if you'd look at [this official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#onAdLeftApplication()) for "AdListener",
you would see this description for "onAdLeftApplication()"-Event:

> public void onAdLeftApplication ()
>
> Called when an ad leaves the application (e.g., to go to the browser).

Now i'm wondering how i could trigger "onAdRETURNSAfterLeftApplication"-kinda return event. I know there are "onResume(), onPause()", but that's not precise enough for my purposes. What's the deal with having "onAdLeftApplication()" when there is no opposite event for that Call? Doesn't make no sense for me:/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#onAdClosed()) also states:

> public void onAdClosed ()
>
> Called when the user is about to return to the application after clicking on an ad.

There's no need for "onAdRETURNSAfterLeftApplication" because the onAdClosed() callback handles that.